# json.loads failed with JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to get information from the Yahoo web site with the following code:

```
import json, requests

response = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/options?p=AAPL")
output = json.loads(response.text)
print(output)
```

Yet i'm getting this error message:

```
File "C:/Users/ziggy/.spyder-py3/untitled4.py", line 4, in <module>
    output = json.loads(response.text)

  File "C:\Users\ziggy\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\ziggy\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\ziggy\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Comment: When I go to the link you provide, there is a regular website there, not JSON. It should not be too surprising that trying to parse HTML as JSON fails.

Answer (score 2):

Really unclear what you're trying to achieve here considering the response is an HTML page.

But, ignoring that, if we're just talking about getting rid of the error, serialize the response first with `json.dumps`:

```
import json, requests

response = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/options?p=AAPL")
encoded_response = json.dumps(response.text)
output = json.loads(encoded_response)
print(output)
```